# One query to find every child with one ref

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Today i'm in front of a problem. I'm using express, mongodb with mongoose to handle the back-end of my application.

I got one model with a ObjectId reference to his parent. I want to retrieve every documents that contain this parent. But i'm receiving only the name of the parent not the id.

The only solution that i found it's to do a first query to find the id then one more to find my documents. I want to know if that's possible to do that in one query ?

My Model :

```
const childSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    _exampleParent: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'parents',
    }

});
```

My query :

```
Parent.findOne({name:req.query.parent}, function(err, values){
   if(err) return next(err);
   Child.find({_exampleParent:values.id},
       'name',
       function(err, values){
           if(err) return next(err);
           res.send(values);
       }
    );
});
```

Thanks guys !

Comment: If name will be unique then instead using id inside child you could use name, otherwise you will need to query by name to find id like you do now

Answer (score 0):

You can populate "child" and filter with parent's name afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Do This, By Changing The Schema:

```
Pass Reference Of Child To Parent Instead of parent reference to the child.
Below I am just showing an example of how to do this, do consider your variable names as mine can differ:

var parentSchema = new Schema({name:{
        type:'string'
    },
    children:[{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
             ref:"child"}]
});
var childSchema = new Schema({name:{type:'string'}});?
var child = mongoose.model('child',childSchema);
var parent = mongoose.model('parent',parentSchema);
```

Now To Retrieve:

```
parent.findOne({name:req.query.name}).populate('child').then((result)=>{
  console.log(result.children) //will be an array of all the children having the same parent.
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But is that a way to do it with my Schema ? Because i want to get the parent inside my child to avoid two query when i'm going to create my child.